# How to find CID of SD card in MFC application

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, sd-card

I need to identify each SD card and block or allow individually using MFC application .I tried with PNP id but its not working.Is there is any way to find the CID of Sd card ?

```
iRetValDeviceType = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DevInfoData, SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS, &dwDataTypeDeviceType, (PBYTE)pszBufferDeviceType, dwBuffSizeDeviceType, &dwBuffSizeDeviceType); 

  CM_Get_Device_ID(DevInfoData.DevInst,pzsBufferPnpId,MAX_PATH,0); 
  csPnpId = (CString)pzsBufferPnpId;                
  auto itSearch = NonStorageMap.find(csPnpId);

   if(itSearch != NonStorageMap.end())
    {
       //pnp id found in map -->allow the device
    }
   else 
   {
     if( (StrStrI(pszBufferDeviceType,"PCISTOR")) || (StrStrI(pszBufferDeviceType,"SD"))
       {

       //pnp id not found in map -->block the device    
       lRetVal = DisableDevice(&hDevInfo,&DevInfoData, DICS_STOP, bRebootRequired);//DICS_DISABLE

      }
   }
```

Comment: You probably need to consume the appropriate interface. What have you tried so far?

Comment: AFAIK there is no special solution, layer in MFC to wrap such functionality. Must use "raw windows API"